# Minifabric custom network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I am setting up a hyperledger fabric environment using the [Minifabric tool](https://github.com/litong01/minifabric). I am specifying the structure of my custom network in the spec.yaml file in the working directory:

```
fabric:
cas:
- "ca1.university.com"
- "ca2.university1.com"
- "ca3.university2.com"
- "ca4.org.com"
- "ca5.org.com"
peers: 
- "peer1.university1.com"
- "peer2.university1.com"
- "peer3.university1.com"
- "peer4.university1.com"
- "peer5.university1.com"
- "peer6.university1.com"
- "peer7.university1.com"
- "peer8.university1.com"
- "peer9.university1.com"
- "peer1.university2.com"
- "peer2.university2.com"
- "peer3.university2.com"
- "peer4.university2.com"
- "peer5.university2.com"
- "peer6.university2.com"
- "peer7.university2.com"
- "peer8.university2.com"
- "peer1.organization_x.com"
- "peer2.organization_x.com"
- "peer3.organization_x.com"
- "peer1.organization_y.com"
- "peer2.organization_y.com"
- "peer3.organization_y.com"
- "peer1.organization_z.com"
- "peer2.organization_z.com"
- "peer3.organization_z.com"
orderers:
- "orderer1.university1.com"
- "orderer2.university1.com"
- "orderer3.university1.com"
- "orderer1.university2.com"
- "orderer2.university2.com"
- "orderer3.university2.com"
- "orderer1.organization_x.com"
- "orderer1.organization_y.com"
- "orderer1.organization_z.com"
settings:
  ca:
    FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC: DEBUG
  peer:
    FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC: DEBUG
  orderer:
    FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC: DEBUG
```

I gave the "./minifab up" command and got the following error:
[image]
Am I specifying the spec.yaml file in a wrong way? What could be the problem? TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The organization that you've specified in `spec.yaml` is `*.university.com`. The default organization is `org0.example.com` and you can see that in the error as well `Default option org is org0.example.com which does not exist in your spec, use -o to specify one`.

`minifab` is a bash file which in turn executes `main.sh`(`/home/main.sh "$@"`). `main.sh` accepts many arguments such as `-c channel-name`, `-s database-type`, and among them, one is `-o organization` as you can see [here](https://github.com/litong01/minifabric/blob/master/main.sh#L49). If you're not using default organization and also not specifying one using the flag `-o` or `--organization`, then you'll get this error.

You can see the `CURRENT_ORG` value in the image you attached and the value is `org0.example.com`.

So, I suggest you to either use the default organization name or pass a new organization name by using the flag `-o`.

Comment: Thank you. Can I change the main.sh file instead, though? Also, what is the role for the default organization?

Comment: I won't recommend you to alter main.sh until you're sure what you are doing. To understand the role of an organization, you should read Hyperledger Fabric Introduction part, but  for now, you can start from these two links https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/glossary.html#organization, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54711075/in-hyperledger-fabric-what-is-an-organization-and-peer

Comment: after specifying the organization I got this error https://ibb.co/MS7c76L. What could be the problem?

Comment: Could you ask another question involving all the steps that came after you passed the `-o` flag, because this might be a totally different issue and might not necessarily have anything to do with the earlier problem.